# Does anyone know what this purple plant is? (picture taken in Turkey)

Tags: species-identification, botany

Is anyone familiar with this plant species, picture taken in the Dalaman region of Turkey. It has large purple leaves.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This shrub is called *Tradescantia pallida*. You can read more about this shrub on this website https://florafaunaweb.nparks.gov.sg/Special-Pages/plant-detail.aspx?id=2521

I hope this helps you